# R selenium error

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to run RSelenium for some scraping purposes.

```
library(RSelenium)

checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
```

I am facing an error after running:

```
remDr$open()
```

> Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata =
>   toJSON(serverOpts)) :

any idea how this error can be tackled ?

Comment: It works for me but it opens firefox by default, do you have firefox installed?  This is what you're calling by default: remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "firefox")

Comment: Yes i do have Firefox installed . But still its failing .

Comment: I also get a warning on running`startServer()` command.

`Warning message:
running command '"java" -jar "C:/Users/Pankaj/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/RSelenium/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar" -log "C:/Users/Pankaj/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/RSelenium/bin/sellog.txt"' had status 127`

Comment: you have an up to date installed java right ? I think 127 has to do with path variables, so maybe your installation is not ok or you should add manually java to path

Comment: No no, I'm talking setting the PATH system variable, it's done outside of R. Google about it to understand better. The line giving the warning calls "java", but it assumes the system knows where to look for java, that's what setting the PATH does. I'm really no authority on all this, but that's what i would investigate.

Comment: Well , did the same but no luck at all .

Answer (score 0):

When you download the selenium standalone server,the problem will be solved.

```
checkForServer(dir = 'the workspace's dirname',update=T)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
```